# Create charts in excel sheet [ in same sheet along with data C#]

Tags: c#, excel

Can we create charts in excel sheet passing data directly from datatable and then bind baar and pie charts with data and on the same sheet can also have many other values in different cells passed by c# code.

Please see attached image for clear view.

Thanks[image: w]

Answer (score 0):

It's unfortunately not that easy :(. You need to use the OpenXMLSDK.
The best way is to create a template excel file with charts in it and write data to the excel sheets, then set the data range of the charts to the data section.

OpenSDK-Download:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124

Comment: Thanks for reply,I have MS Office 2010, so I can use Microsoft.Office.Interop for the same?

can you please give me direction for the code, how to pass data range to charts .

Comment: Data in other cells are not static, This is also from database, and how can we pass data to chart from datatable? please let me know how to write this in c#.

Comment: If you can do it with the Microsoft.Office.Interop, then do it because openxmlsdk is unfortunately very complex. I couldn't do it because we need to apply our application on a server environment where Excel is not installled there.

Comment: For writing and reading values i used ClosedXML and , but this bib is rather slow and it doesn't support charting :(. Setting range for charts is different from chart to chart but you can use the open xml sdk productivity tool in order to generate some c# code for you. Then you can extract the necessary code section and do some refactorings.